# web.config in sharepoint webpart project

Tags: user-controls, web-config, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I'm creating a sharepoint project with custom webpart that includes custom user controls.

Is there any way to include a web.config file in this project?

Some of the references I'm including use the web.config file.

Thanks

Comment: My problem is that some references that I'm including need to access a web.config to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Property bags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647766.aspx) for storing configuration settings. Take a look on this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/11/25/using-sharepoint-propertybag-in-the-context-of-search/).

You have several options to work with the Property Bags:

- SharePoint Designer
- PowerShell
- Custom code
- Codeplex solutions (as [SharePoint Property Bag Settings](http://pbs2013.codeplex.com/), that provides a farm solution to work with the Property Bag using the SharePoint UI).

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe there is no way.
You have to include your entries in the SharePoint web.config file.

The correct way is not to use a web.config, but if you really need it then use the SharePoint web.config.